# :E focus current filename in directory view

Tags: vim

Entering `:E` directory mode always shows the top of the menu, but if I have many files, I have to scroll a lot.  Can I have directory view focus the current filename, or as close to the filename as possible(if not written)?

If the file is not written, its because sometimes when I do `:E`, it's because I opened the wrong file
If I am trying to open `dir1/dir2/dir3/filename.txt`, and I screw up and instead do:

`:new dir1/dir2/dir3/filenam`

Now, I'd like to do `:E`, and have the dir3 start off in the `f` section, rather than at the very top of the directory

Even if I open the correct file, I still would like the `:E` view to start at the currently open file( or close to the name as possible )

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is to perform a search using the filename of the file you were in when you issued the command `:Explore`. Usually the filename of this *alternate file* is contained in register `@#` (see `:h quote#`), but netrw being a bit peculiar this doesn't seem to be updated when entering the directory listing.

This means you will have to figure out and somehow pass on the term you want to search for before moving on to the netrw buffer. I chose to do this by parsing the name of current file (`expand('%:t')`) to the command sequence `:Explore` executes by re-defining the command in `.vimrc` to include a search for this term:

```
autocmd VimEnter * com! -nargs=* -bar -bang -count=0 -complete=dir  Explore execute "call netrw#Explore(<count>,0,0+<bang>0,<q-args>)" . ' | call SearchNetrw(' . string(expand('%:t')) . ')'
```

`au VimEnter` is needed, because the netrw plugin is sourced after `.vimrc` has been loaded and otherwise this command would be overwritten using the default definition. The name of current file is passed into a call to a function `SearchNetrw`, which I defined as such:

```
function! SearchNetrw(fname)
    if ! search('\V\^' . a:fname . '\$')
        call search('^' . substitute(a:fname, '\w\zs.*', '', '') . '.*\/\@<!$')
    endif
endfunction
```

The function first tries to search using the whole name of the file which was given to it as parameter, and if it is not found, it searches using the first *word character* of the filename (to ensure dotfiles etc. are handled elegantly), and ignoring folders (lines ending in `/` in the listing). Other than that, I didn't include any handling of special cases such as what happens when you are a buffer without a name, even though in that specific case it behaves quite gracefully taking you to first file in the listing.

Comment: Eyyyy, very nice.  Thanks much!